# Need to call var or let without setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i wanna ask about my code. It is working. But when i make update in firebase it gives to setState only "false" because it took only changed data... and i wanna ask, is here a way how to call my data without giving them to setState first?

I tried to call function like this.myf(userTeam, userAccepted) and then call it in seperate function, but its not working

```
  _getNotAccepted() {
    uzivateleRef.on("value", snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      let seznamNepotvrzenych = Object.keys(data).map((key, i) => {
        let getAllUsersUID = data[key].uid;
        let dataTeam = snapshot.child("/" + getAllUsersUID + "/teams").val();

        let teamInfo = Object.keys(dataTeam).map((key, i) => {
          var n = dataTeam[key];
          var userTeam = n.teamID;
          var userAccepted = n.accepted;

          this.setState({ userTeam, userAccepted });
        });
        console.log(data[key].fname + " je: " + this.state.userAccepted);
        if (this.state.userAccepted == false) {
          if (this.state.userTeam == this.state.actualUserTeam) {
            return (
              <View key={key} style={styles.acceptedPpl}>
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.AcceptedEmail}>{data[key].email}</Text>
                  {data[key].fname !== "" ? (
                    <Text style={styles.jmenoPrijmeni}>
                      {data[key].fname} {data[key].lname}
                    </Text>
                  ) : (
                    <Text style={styles.jmenoPrijmeni}>
                      (Ještě nevyplnil jméno)
                    </Text>
                  )}
                </View>
                <View style={styles.acceptedIcons}>
                  <Ionicon
                    name="md-checkmark-circle-outline"
                    size={30}
                    color="#89c440"
                    onPress={() => this.addRoleToUser(data[key].uid, this.state.userTeam)}
                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      borderLeftWidth: 1,
                      borderLeftColor: "#DCDCDC",
                      marginLeft: 15,
                      marginRight: 15,
                      height: 20,
                      marginTop: 5
                    }}
                  />
                  <Ionicon
                    name="md-trash"
                    size={30}
                    color="#616161"
                    onPress={() =>
                      this.showAlert(
                        data[key].uid,
                        data[key].email,
                        this.state.userTeam
                      )
                    }
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          }
        }
      });
      this.setState({ seznamNepotvrzenych });
    });
  }
```

How i say, code it working but little bit buggy and after changing database I must call a whole function again for all data and not only changed data

I want to have this code:

```
let teamInfo = Object.keys(dataTeam).map((key, i) => {
  var n = dataTeam[key];
  var userTeam = n.teamID;
  var userAccepted = n.accepted;

  this.setState({ userTeam, userAccepted });
});
console.log(data[key].fname + " je: " + this.state.userAccepted);
if (this.state.userAccepted == false) {
  if (this.state.userTeam == this.state.actualUserTeam) { ...
```

to something like this:

```
let teamInfo = Object.keys(dataTeam).map((key, i) => {
  var n = dataTeam[key];
  var userTeam = n.teamID;
  var userAccepted = n.accepted;

  return(userTeam, userAccepted)
});
console.log(data[key].fname + " je: " + this.state.userAccepted);
if (userAccepted == false) {
  if (userTeam == this.state.actualUserTeam) { ...
```

Comment: You can subscribe to firebase data change in componentDidMount method, and then update your state if there is any. Look firebase documentation about that.

Comment: ye i know that, but i have like 4 this functions, i dont want to refresh them all again and again. I just want to store data only for this function and not to all in same file, if you know what i mean